# WPF DataGrid map middle mouse button click to ctrl + left click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to implement a feature where clicking the middle mouse button works the same as using ctrl + left click.

This will let the user select multiple cells with just the middle mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

In your markup, hook up a handler to the `PreviewMouseDown` event:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" PreviewMouseDown="MyDataGrid_PreviewMouseDown" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell"></DataGrid>
```

Then in your code behind, you can do something like this:

```
private void MyDataGrid_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Middle && e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        MyDataGrid.Focus();

        DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

        // Traverse the visual tree looking for DataGridCell
        while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridCell))
            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);

        if (dep == null)
        {
            // Didn't find DataGridCell
            return;
        }

        DataGridCell cell = dep as DataGridCell;

        if (cell != null)                
        {
            DataGridCellInfo cellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(cell);
            if(!MyDataGrid.SelectedCells.Contains(cellInfo))
            {
                // The cell is not already selected, add it to the selection
                MyDataGrid.SelectedCells.Add(new DataGridCellInfo(cell));
            }
            else
            {
                // Cell is already part of selection, remove it (same behaviour as ctrl+left click)
                MyDataGrid.SelectedCells.Remove(cellInfo);
            }

        }
    } 
}
```